# How to reinstall consul on a different namespace?

Tags: helm, consul, kubectl

I have installed consul on default namespace using helm.

```
helm install -f config.yaml consul hashicorp/consul --version "0.32.1"
```

I tried uninstall of consul using

```
helm delete consul
```

And installing again using.

```
kubectl create namespace consul
helm install -f config.yaml consul hashicorp/consul --version "0.32.1" --namespace consul
```

Now, getting error as below.

[image: error]

I followed [this](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/service-mesh-deploy?in=consul/gs-consul-service-mesh) approach

Answer (score 0):

Resource already used in some namespace
You need to clean up first and then install it again

Please check the topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964532/helm-not-creating-the-resources

Comment: helm delete should do that clean up right? What we need to do if any resources exist? Because it is hard to identify the bread crumbs if there are many deployments on the cluster.

Comment: Did you try --debug with helm install

Comment: there is a lot of commands to find resource used one of them is using kubectl get all -n <namespace> | grep ...
Solution number 2 is: helm list  for more info check: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_list/

Answer (score 0):

There are some CustomResourceDefinition which are showing

kubectl get CustomResourceDefinition

But didn't see any when I type.

kubectl get all

Now, as it is test environment, I deleted them using.

kubectl delete CustomResourceDefinition --all

Now, it is working.